# How Do You Forward Network Traffic From WiFi to Ethernet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I have two computers: Computer 1 (Ubuntu Desktop) has a WiFi connection and an Ethernet port, and Computer 2 (Ubuntu Server) only has an Ethernet port. I would like to have Computer 1 share its internet connection with Computer 2 over an Ethernet connection between the two computers.

What I have done so far:

- I have connected the two computers together using an Ethernet cable.
- I have created LAN for the two computers

  - Each computer has a static IP (configured in `/etc/netplan/*`): Computer 1 is configured as `192.168.2.1/24`, and Computer 2 is configured as `192.168.2.140/24` with its default gateway `192.168.2.1`.
  - Both computers are able to ping eachother.
- I have tried to set up `iptable` forwarding on Computer 1 between the WiFi, and Ethernet interfaces, `wlp5s0`, and `enp4s0` respectively (found from the output of `ifconfig`), but I haven't had any luck. My knowledge falls short with configuring `iptables`, so every guide I have found has, more or less, been a shot in the dark.
- IP forwarding has been enabled with `sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

I have heard of "network bridging", but I am unsure if this is something that can be used in this scenario.

> **ASIDE:** I know about using the "shared to other computers" option in the network manager. I have used it, and it works successfully. What I don't like about it is that I don't have the ability to set a static IP address. Plus I would like to know how to do all this from the command line anyways.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I'm unsure what IP to use in place of their `192.168.0.0/24`. They don't seem to specify. I tried `192.168.2.0/14`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

- Set the default gateway for the server to be the IP address of the desktop.

```
  ip route add 0.0.0.0 via 192.168.2.1
```

- On the desktop: change the line in ***/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward*** to ***1***
- Set masquerading in iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlp5s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp5s0 -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
```

- we needed to add a post route (this was discovered in a breakout chat)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.139
```

- uncomment the line ***net.ipv4.ip forward=1*** in the file ***/etc/sysctl.conf***
- save the iptables:

```
sudo iptables-save -t nat
```

Comment: check the update: I changed it to 192.168.2.1

Comment: What is the purpose of the first command? Why not just change `gateway4` to `192.168.2.1` in `/etc/netplan` (as I have already tried that)? Also I have already enabled IP forwarding.

Comment: Where di you enable ip forwarding? on the desktop? What is the output of ```ip route``` on both?

Comment: For IP tables, perhaps set masquerading:

Comment: Did you uncomment ***net.ipv4.ip forward=1*** in ***/etc/sysctl.conf*** ?

Comment: IP forwarding was enabled on the desktop, Computer 1, yeah. IP route for computer 1 yields: `default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp5s0 proto dhcp metric 600` 
`169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp5s0 scope link metric 1000` 
`192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.139 metric 600` 
`192.168.2.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1 metric 100`, and for computer 2 yields: `192.168.2.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.140`

Comment: yeah, all of that should be done on the desktop except for adding the route, which should be done on the server. What is the output of ip route on both? also what is the output of *traceroute 8.8.8.8* on the server? Are you able to ping 8.8.8.8? Could it be a DNS issue?

Comment: As for uncommenting net.ipv4.ip forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf, I thought that was for permanently setting it on boot? `sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should do it temporarily no?

Comment: is this the whole output for the server? ```192.168.2.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.140```? If so , then it is missing the default route. Try this command on the server ```ip route add 0.0.0.0 via 192.168.2.1```.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, yeah it also has `default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp4s0`

Comment: ^*/$ `proto static`/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124421/discussion-between-shgun8-and-kalcifer).